# validator is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button with a class of `.subscribe`, but when I click on the button it says validator not defined, and that's the function I want to run on the button click, please why does it still bring that error

```
var $form = $('#payment-form');
$form.find('.subscribe').on('click', payWithStripe);

/* If you're using Stripe for payments */
validator = $form.validate({
rules: {
    cardNumber: {
        required: true,
        cardNumber: true
    },
    cardExpiry: {
        required: true,
        cardExpiry: true
    },
    cardCVC: {
        required: true,
        cardCVC: true
    }
    },
   highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.form-control').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
},
unhighlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.form-control').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
},
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    $(element).closest('.form-group').append(error);
}
});
function payWithStripe(e) {
e.preventDefault();

/* Abort if invalid form data */
if (!validator.form()) {
 //   alert("krkrk");
    return;
}

/* Visual feedback */
$form.find('.subscribe').html('Validating <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>').prop('disabled', true);

var PublishableKey = 'pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh'; // Replace with your API publishable key
Stripe.setPublishableKey(PublishableKey);

/* Create token */
var expiry = $form.find('[name=cardExpiry]').payment('cardExpiryVal');
var ccData = {
    number: $form.find('[name=cardNumber]').val().replace(/\s/g,''),
    cvc: $form.find('[name=cardCVC]').val(),
    exp_month: expiry.month, 
    exp_year: expiry.year
 };

Stripe.card.createToken(ccData, function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    if (response.error) {
        /* Visual feedback */
        $form.find('.subscribe').html('Try again').prop('disabled', false);
        /* Show Stripe errors on the form */
   $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
        $form.find('.payment-errors').closest('.row').show();
    } else {
        /* Visual feedback */
        $form.find('.subscribe').html('Processing <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>');
        /* Hide Stripe errors on the form */
        $form.find('.payment-errors').closest('.row').hide();
        $form.find('.payment-errors').text("");
        // response contains id and card, which contains additional card   details            
        console.log(response.id);
        console.log(response.card);
        var token = response.id;
        // AJAX - you would send 'token' to your server here.
        $.post('/account/stripe_card_token', {
                token: token
            })
            // Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
            .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $form.find('.subscribe').html('Payment successful <i class="fa fa-check"></i>');
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $form.find('.subscribe').html('There was a  problem').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
                /* Show Stripe errors on the form */
                $form.find('.payment-errors').text('Try refreshing the page  and trying again.');
                $form.find('.payment-errors').closest('.row').show();
            });
    }
});
}
/* Fancy restrictive input formatting via jQuery.payment library*/
$('input[name=cardNumber]').payment('formatCardNumber');
$('input[name=cardCVC]').payment('formatCardCVC');
$('input[name=cardExpiry').payment('formatCardExpiry');

/* Form validation using Stripe client-side validation helpers */
jQuery.validator.addMethod("cardNumber", function(value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || Stripe.card.validateCardNumber(value);
}, "Please specify a valid credit card number.");

jQuery.validator.addMethod("cardExpiry", function(value, element) {    
/* Parsing month/year uses jQuery.payment library */
value = $.payment.cardExpiryVal(value);
return this.optional(element) || Stripe.card.validateExpiry(value.month, value.year);
}, "Invalid expiration date.");

jQuery.validator.addMethod("cardCVC", function(value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || Stripe.card.validateCVC(value);
}, "Invalid CVC.");



paymentFormReady = function() {
if ($form.find('[name=cardNumber]').hasClass("success") &&
    $form.find('[name=cardExpiry]').hasClass("success") &&
    $form.find('[name=cardCVC]').val().length > 1) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}

$form.find('.subscribe').prop('disabled', true);
var readyInterval = setInterval(function() {
if (paymentFormReady()) {
    $form.find('.subscribe').prop('disabled', false);
    clearInterval(readyInterval);
}
}, 250);
```

Comment: From the question it's not getting clear, but it may be because the form is created after the js is parsed. If that's the case you will need to bind the event like so:
`$('#payment-form').on('click', 'subscribe', payWithStripe)` does that helps? P.S or depending on the `HTML` maybe providing the selector like `var selector = $form.find('.subscribe')` and then `.on('click', selector, payWithStripe);`

Comment: The validator function doesn't work, that's my question

Comment: From what I see, your questions is - `The validator function is defined, please why does it still bring that error`. So to me the function probably is working fine, but on click you got an error that the function is not defined.. However, I won't spam you, I wrote you one possible solution, try it if you want...

Comment: When i use `$('#payment-form').on('click', 'subscribe', payWithStripe)` there's an error, `$form.validate is not a function`

Comment: @AdokiyeIruene, define var validator

Comment: @whoami I did that it brings 2 errors `$form.validate is not a function` and `Cannot read property 'form' of undefined`